# Node.js async recursive function with callback

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, recursion

**Task**: I need to recursively walk through a json object and make certain changes to the keys. I will be handling objects with varying depths, and varying sizes. When the function hits a key whose value is an object, it is called again on that object.

**Problem 1.**: Doing this as a synchronous function, I noticed that large json objects were returning incomplete. Using the the async library, `async.forEach` solves the problem of handling long tasks and returning only when finished, but...

**Problem 2.**: It seems that the async function loses concurrency (?) when it is called recursively (pointed out in the code snippet).

To test this idea, I removed the recursive function call and it worked (but without recursion), and I got a callback. When I add the function call back in, I get `TypeError: results is not a function` .

This leads me to think that async with callback *and* recursive functions don't mix in node. Is there a way to achieve both?

**Possible Fix**: I could run a separate function to count all the keys and use a counter as my control in a simple `for` loop, rather than letting `forEach` handle the control. That seems a bit inefficient, no?

Here's the code:

```js
function fixJsonKeys(obj, results) {

    async.forEach(Object.keys(obj), function(key, callback) {

        if (typeof obj[key] == 'object') {
                
            // do stuff to json key, then call the function
            // on the nested object
            
            fixJsonKeys(obj[key]);

            callback();  // <-- how does this work with recursion??

        }

        else {
            
            // do stuff to json key

            callback();
        }

    }, function(err) {

        if (err) return next(err);
        
        // obj keys fixed, now return completed object

        results(obj);

    });
}
```

**EDIT**: hard to format in comments, so:

@Laksh and @Suhail: I tried your suggestions and same outcomes. If I remove the callback from the `if` condition, the `async.forEach` still looks to confirm that it has handled the top level keys (I think).

For example, say I have 3 top level keys, and one of them has a nested object:

```
[key1] (no callback, do recursion)

    --[subKey1]
    --[subKey2]

[key2] (callback)

[key3] (callback)
```

`async.forEach` is still looking for a callback on action taken for key1. Do I have this correct?

Comment: You could only the callback in the base case of recursion

Comment: Just remove the `callback` after the recursive call inside the `if` block

Comment: @Queenqueg, what does the input for `fixJsonKeys` look like? And what is the expected output?

Comment: @Queenqueg, using `async.forEach` because your synchronous approach failed makes this an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) – show your synchronous code problem

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using recursive functions here, you don't need to call `callback()` inside the if condition.

This is because your recursive call will return to the existing `callback()` in if once the entire recursive stack finished for that particular `obj[key]`.

Recursive function return only when the base condition is true, in your case when if condition fails so it will automatically call `callback()` from else block.